# editing guidelines for Unix SE

Tags: discussion, editing, etiquette

So you guys have granted me enough rep to edit. :D

**But** before I dig into people's questions/answers, what **conventions/rules/guidelines** should be followed when editing?

Answer (score 3):

Obviously we can come up with our own policies, but this has been [discussed on the main meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=editing+%5betiquette%5d) quite a bit, so that's probably a good place to start; [What is the etiquette for modifying posts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11474/what-is-the-etiquette-for-modifying-posts) is particularly helpful. There's also a [blog entry](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/03/the-great-edit-wars/) on it

Answer (score 1):

Up to this point I have only considered doing the following, all of which I feel are within the etiquette of this site:

- Tags
- Poor Formatting (ie, properly formatting code)
- Edits to commands that are either obviously wrong or corrected in the comments. (for example, `find -type -f` to `find -type f`)
- Adding/fixing links (especially since new users have a limit on the links they can post).

I think the following *could* be appropriate, but would like to see what others think:

- Fixing the grammar of posts written by users who are not very fluent in English. I don't mean fixing every grammar/spelling mistake (I have certainly made many), but simply making questions readable if they are good questions simply written by someone who doesn't speak English well.
- Putting Warnings on code that could be especially harmful.
- Adding a small amount of information to an otherwise excellent post.  Often someone has 90% of the answer and I only see the need to point one small thing out.  I often post this as a comment, but sometimes it would be nice to have it as part of the answer.

Comment: anything NOT to do? How do you feel about clarifying titles?

Comment: I think clarifying titles as another worthwhile editing task.  In terms of what not to do, I would basically avoid changing the content of the question or answers unless they are community wikis.

Comment: I'm fine with all of those things; I'll rewrite an entire question if it's poorly written, as long as I think I'm keeping the author's intent the same. I'm much more hesitant to change content, as I'm always afraid of introducing a mistake inadvertently, but as long as you're quite certain your change is accurate it's probably fine

Comment: @Stefan I've only clarified maybe once... because someone was like "what blah"? and the person had 'tagged' the post but not otherwise mentioned what in any of it.  I mostly try not to change that kind of stuff unless it's glaringly obvious, or causing a problem